# Help with vinyl planks on damaged subfloor

Tags: vinyl-flooring

It previously  had sheet vinyl and  still has some adhesive  residue  on it.  How do I cover up the residue?  I can't  get it completely  off.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to put on top? Instead of the vinyl that it is.

Comment: The sheet vinyl has been removed.  It is a floating floor  and shouldn't  stick to the subfloor.  The manufacturer   (us floors) says not to use adhesive remover or any citrus  cleanser.  I have talked to them twice and got conflicting  answers.  One person said to put felt paper over it and the second one specifically  said not to do that.  They said to put a layer of concrete paste.  They couldn't  give me a brand name.

Comment: Is this below grade (like a basement)? What LVT are you using (some need underpayment and perfectly smooth subfloors and others do not)?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that serious application of a CARBIDE "paint scraper" will remove some truly miserable adhesive residue in a purely mechanical fashion. Don't even bother with the steel blade types, they proved useless.

Typically have a narrow tungsten carbide blade that is clamped, and has two sides so you can flip it once for a fresh edge before replacing or resharpening. Not even terribly expensive.

Comment: I've had stuff so bad that I went and bought a 4" scraper blade for an SDS chipping hammer. I think it was *blacktop*. And after that you still need a floor machine.

Answer (score 0):

The vinyl planks will need a hard smooth surface to lay over.  Typically you would scrape the adhesive clean off then use floor patch and self leveling underlayment as required to get the floor smooth and even.

A a wood based laminate floor your could float right over the adhesive because they all typically have or require a thin foam like underlayment that could float right over the old adhesive as long as you got off the peaks and filled the dips in the over floor.

Answer (score 0):

Get as much as you can off. Go over it a level off the low spots . Add a 1/4 inch underlayment plywood such as louan . Then your pad for floor , Get a good pad mine was of poor thickness and will never use again..And fill all areas !/8 , and a good pad will take care of the rest.